# convert image pixels from square to hexagonal

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

How can i convert the pixels of an image from square to hexagonal? Doing so i need to extract the rgb values from each hex pixel. Is there any library or function that simplify this process?

Example : Mona Lisa Hexagonal Pixel Shape

[image]
Nothing tried.  Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would help to explain what you mean by "convert the pixels . . . from square to hexagonal".  In particular, clarify what arrangement of hexagonal pixels you have in mind.

Comment: @P.Pearson i want to get the rgb values of an image wich is represented with hexagonal pixels instead of square pixels. An image with hex pixels have slightly different rgb values than square pixels ( 1 px example) , this is what i need.

Comment: If we compare the same pixel from an img for example a squared pixel with  position (1,1) with a hexagonal px in the same position the rgb values should be different right?

Comment: Where is this hexagonal-pixel image coming from?

Comment: @Eric this is what i want to achieve. To convert the image .. which the pixel shape is hexagonal and not square.

Comment: Mona lisa hexagonal pixel shape : https://postimg.org/image/9b58geur1/27696c6d/

Comment: Challenging.  The "unit cell" that repeats in the hexagonal grid has an aspect ratio of sqrt(3), which will make it incommensurate with _any_ square grid.  To get ideas rolling, maybe overlay the original square grid with a hexagonal grid whose hexagons have the same areas as the squares, then color each hexagon in proportion to its overlap with the squares beneath it.  Tedious geometry, and the code will be slow, but maybe you're not in a hurry.

Comment: What you want to do is to convert an image using an squared grid to an image with an hexagonal grid. Unfortunately, it can only be simulated, the hexagonal grid will be an approximation. But if what you want to achieve of something comparable to the Mona Lisa example, you can down-sample the image using hexagonal neighborhood (but it still an approximation).

Comment: So to check I understand, you want to take an image made of square pixels, and produce another image _of larger hexagonal "pixels"_ **that is still made of square pixels**

Comment: @Eric in the mona lisa example 1 pixel = 1 hex pixel. Maybe the only solution is the simulation of a hexagonal grid like P.Pearson stated.

Comment: @Smindler: What do you want your output file to be? There is no common file format that stores hexagonal pixels.

Comment: @Eric Output in binary , since i have 60 gb of images. I need numerical values after convertion not jpg or image format.

Comment: Congratulations, you chose the only type of format computers can store. That answer isn't useful. Imagine I ask you what language you wrote your question in, and you said "with the keyboard".
Can you give an example of a simple (~10 pixels) black-and-white hex image, and what its array/binary representation should be?

Comment: @Eric ok isnt true that binary format files  are a lot smaller than their text equivalents and are used for storing large amound of data? From the image i just need rgb values of every pixel simple as that [(255.254.255), .....,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123038/discussion-between-eric-and-smindler).

Comment: @Eric  hdf5 for example , maybe you misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible approach, though I am sure if you are able to write code to read, manipulate and use pixels from a file format that hasn't been invented yet, you should be able to create that file yourself ;-)

You could generate a hexagonal grid, using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows. Here, I am just doing things at the command-line in the Terminal, but there are Python, Perl, PHP, .Net, C/C++ and other bindings too - so take your pick.

First make a grid of hexagons - you'll have to work out the size you need, mine is arbitrary:

```
convert -size 512x256 pattern:hexagons hexagons.png
```

[image]

Now, fill in the hexagons, each with a different colour, I am just doing some examples of flood-filling here to give you the idea. Ideally, you would colour the first (top-left) hexagon with colour `#000` and the next one across with `#001` so that you could iterate through the coordinates of the output image as consecutive colours. Also, depending on your output image size, you may need to use a 32-bit PNG to accommodate the number of hexels (hexagonal pixels).

```
convert hexagons.png                          \
   -fill red - draw "color 100,100 floodfill" \
   -fill blue -draw "color 200,200 floodfill" \
   colouredmask.png
```

[image]

Now iterate through all the colours, making every colour *except* that colour transparent. Note that I have added a black border just so you can see the context on StackOverflow's white background:

```
convert colouredmask.png -fill none +opaque red onecell.png
```

[image]

Now mask the original image with that mask and get the average colour of that one cell and write it to your yet-to-be-invented file format. Repeat for all cells/colours.

Note that the basic hexagon pattern is 30x18, so you should size your grid as multiples of that for it to tesselate properly.

Note that if you have lots of these to process, you should consider using something like **GNU Parallel** to take advantage of multiple cores. So, if you make a script called `ProcessOneImage` and you have 2,000 images to do, you would use:

```
parallel ProcessOneImage ::: *.png
```

and it will keep, say 8, jobs running all the time if your PC has 8 cores. There are many more options, try `man parallel`.

Answer (score 2):

Fred has an Imagemagick script on his site that may do what you want: [STAINEDGLASS](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/stainedglass/index.php)

Comment: Cool script - I think the OP actually wants hexagonal pixels though, rather than a JPEG/PNG file of square pixels showing an image that is processed into hexagons. You may be right though - the question is unclear :-)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I think there is no such a function that is ready for you to perform the lattice conversion, thus you may need to implement the conversion process by yourself.

The lattice conversion is a re-sampling process, and it is also a interpolation process. There are many algorithms that have been developed in the hexagonal image processing papers.

Please see the example for you:
[image]
[image]